# Is there a theory for piecewise differentiable regression polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, continuity, regression

I have an interesting question, I would like to have answered...

I have a very noisy signal $f$, that I want to smoothen out. Using a global regression cannot work, as I don't have a model of the signal (being a measurement of the solution of an ODE). 
I would like to use multiple regressions $p_1$, $p_2$, etc. to have
$$
\min_{p_1} \int_{x_0}^{x_1} (f(x)-p_1(x))^2 dx$$
and 
$$\min_{p_2} \int_{x_1}^{x_2} (f(x)-p_2(x))^2 dx
$$
This however is very easy (use Matlab polyfit on each interval) and not a problem. But I want to go further...
I want to enforce $p_1(x_1)=p_2(x_1)$ and $p_1'(x_1) = p_2'(x_1)$ to have a continous and smooth result. This will ofcourse increase the regression error.

Is there a theory for this? Or do I need to make my own algorithm via optimization toolboxes?

Comment: One word comes to my mind... spline.

Comment: Spline interpolation uses either all my many points for interpolation not reducing all my noise. If I made a spline with only a few parts, I need interpolation points, that I don't have (as $f(x_1)$ is noisy). I would also ignore all other points between the  break-points.

Comment: @Laray : I doubt that a general theory is presently available for piecewise polynomial regression. For piecewise linear regression a method based on integral equation fitting is shown with examples in : https://fr.scribd.com/document/380941024/Regression-par-morceaux-Piecewise-Regression-pdf . But this theory isn't advanced enough for general piecewise polynomial regression. It could be used in some very simple particular cases (not published in the above referenced paper).

Comment: Looks nice, but (sadly) I don't understand a single word of French. I will go with an Optimization with equality constraints

Comment: You said you use Matlab... so I meant  www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smoothing-splines.html

Comment: I faced a similar problem for fitting experimental data coming from the lab. In my case, the $p_i(x)$ are defined functions (more complex than polynomials. Same constraints **plus** the fact that $x_1$ was to be be adjusted (not a point in the data set but more or less located). I solved it using constrained optimization for a given $x_1$ and polished the solution. It worked nice. I do not think that there is any theory behind.

Comment: @JJacquelin. Good link to your recent paper. Cheers.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici : I agree with your pragmatic approach. In practice solving these kind of problems (which are very complicated on purely theoretical viewpoint) can be overcome with iterative numerical calculus. Trying to solve them directly, without recursive calculus, can be considered as a pleasant  chalenge in case of very simple problems. Cheers.